# Add two rows with foreign key - SQL

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django, pyodbc

**I'm worndering how I can add 2 rows, of which 1 depends on another, in 1 transaction.**

```
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES ('malcom.reynolds')

INSERT INTO spaceships (name, owner) 
VALUES ('Serenity', <<Malcom Reynold's row ID>>)
```

---

Reason I an doing is that the library I'm using does not return the rowid, and I need to commit the transaction as less as possible as I'm adding over a few million records!

Just for the record I'm using:

- **SQL Server 2008**
- **Python**
- **pyodbc**

---

**Any idea?** Would be really awesome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in one batch statement:

```
declare @key as int;
insert into users (username)
values ('malcom.reynolds');
set @key = (select scope_identity());
insert into spaceships (name, owner)
values ('Serenity', @key)
```

Comment: thanks for adding the `declare` line, it worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 4):

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259185%28SQL.80%29.aspx

```
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES ('malcom.reynolds');

INSERT INTO spaceships (name, owner) 
VALUES ('Serenity', SCOPE_IDENTITY() )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the T-SQL `scope_identity` to return the new ID from the first `INSERT` statement.

Before your first `INSERT`, declare a variable to hold the value of the new ID:

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue int;
```

Right after your first `INSERT`, add this to set the value of that variable:

`SELECT @ReturnValue = scope_identity()`

Then, you can use the `@ReturnValue` variable in your second `INSERT` in place of :

```
INSERT INTO spaceships (name, owner) 
VALUES ('Serenity', @ReturnValue)
```

Comment: thanks for your awesome reply, it did not work initially as I had to declare the variable and I am a bit inexperienced with T-SQL. Thanks for the explanations :D

Comment: @RadiantHex: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated my example for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use OUTPUT. This is hadnier when you need to return more than one field or are doing a multitrow insert to begin with. You can use a table variable if you are doing multiple rows instead of an int variable.

```
DECLARE @key int
insert into users (username)
output inserted.userid 
values ('malcom.reynolds'); 

insert into spaceships (name, owner) 
values ('Serenity', @key)
```